# if statement homework error, how do i fix it?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, if-statement, printing

I have some intro to python homework I can't seem to get right.

The question is :  "Write a program to determine how much to tip the server in a restaurant. The tip should be 15% of the check, with a minimum of $2." And the hint suggested to use "if" statement.

This is what I've got so far but I get an error '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Bill = input("Enter bill amount")

if  Bill > 13.4:   print(Bill*0.15)

else:
print(2)

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string.  Therefore `Bill` is a string, and you cannot compare strings to numbers.

You can convert the input value to a floating-point value using `float()`, like this:

```
Bill = float(input("Enter bill amount"))
```

Comment: Could you help me create a program for my homework by any chance? I've been trying to come up with something for almost 2 hours now lol